# Implement Pull to Refresh feature in Core Plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Hi I want to implement the pull to refresh feature in CP so that I can reload data by using this gesture. I did some research that the apple built in gesture features rely on tableview or scrollview. Is it possible to make use of the Gesture Recognizers that have been built in the Core Plot library? Or is there any ready made methods within the CP? I saw some people put their CP within a scrollview but I guess that will make the performance worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a graph to bounce back if the user pulls the plot past the global plot range (set `allowsMomentum` to `YES` on the plot space). However, this doesn't give you enough control of the bounce to pause it and display the spinner that is normally displayed during the refresh. You're better off embedding the graph in another view that handles the pull-to-refresh action.

Comment: Liked embedding it to a scroll view? Because I've already made my coreplot graph to scroll (liked what you mentioned), will embedding it to scroll view affect this?

Comment: I added the graph onto a scrollview. I also set plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO; Now my graph don't scroll at all... Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Alternatively, if I'm using the old way (embedding CP in UIView instead of SV), how do I execute my codes when the user pull the plot past the global plot range? I can compensate the spinner effect by running my own activity indicator.

Comment: `allowsUserInteraction = NO` does what it says—it disables user interaction (e.g., scrolling and zooming) with the plot space. You can always use a plot space delegate to monitor changes to the plot ranges. When you detect a scroll past the global range, trigger the spinner.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am finding documentation on how to detect how far the user has dragged the graph (liked in scroll view delegate method you can get it by scrollView.contentOffset.y).

Comment: A plot space delegate can compare the current value of the plot range against the global range and determine if the user has pulled past the global range and if so, how far.